# Customize Django comments framework so that the comment does not have to be unique

Tags: django, django-models, django-contrib

I'm customizing the comments model per the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/).

In my specific use case, however, comments are allowed to be blank. The trouble I get into then is that the Comment model is setup with an `unique_together`:

```
unique_together = [('user', 'comment', 'flag')]
```

Any ideas on how I could go about overriding this?

(...or did I start off on the wrong track with using the Comments framework altogether? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like the Comment model has a unique constraint.

[**`Code for models.py`**](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/models.py#L180) for contrib.comments.

It looks like the CommentFlag model has the uniqueness constraint which shouldn't effect you having blank comments.

Your problem must lie elsewhere.

---

<strike>I'm not very familiar with the comments app but here are some ideas you can look at to get around your problem.</strike>

**Warning** I haven't used either of these methods on the comments app so I'm not sure if using these will break any downstream functions of the comments framework. Be sure to look into/test if you decide to use either of these.

That being said, I can think of 2 ways you can approach this.

1. Override the unique together:

   class NonUniqueComment(Comment):
       class Meta(Comment.Meta):
           unique_together = []
2. Make the comments field store Null instead of empty string in the db.

Comment: D'oh! Looks like you are absolutely right. I wonder why my comments aren't posted in that case... So sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Aha. Perhaps check_for_duplicate_comment() in forms.py, should be much easier to fix! Thanks for your help!